# Web developement in using Java in Netbeans

Tags: java, web, netbeans

Is there dual view feature in NetBeans for web development? That is separate views for both design view and source code  view just like in Visual Studio or in Dreamweaver?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Design view is possible in netbeans
Using Palette you can drag element of html JSF JSP etc.
in netbeans Window -> IDE Tools -> Palettes (Ctrl+Shift+8)

Comment: I think the palettes you just suggested gives you drag and drop option to html tools, but my question is that how can I see the website design layout and the source code on separate(split) columns(windows) inside NetBeans? If you have worked with Dreamweaver or Visual Studio, there are three display options which are design view, code view and split view; in fact Dreamweaver has live view option so that you can view the website you're  developing on the fly as if you're in a browser.

Comment: I think you are talking about  visual web application design refer this article ([https://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/visualwebdev/][1])    There is a one way to implement  visual web application design using Visual Web JSF Development for this watch this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DewrvoWXLTQ)

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin in netbeans official web site. I cannot tell the quality or effectiveness of the plugin because i haven't use it so far.

use the following link to download the plugin and do not forget to check the comments.

[Html preview plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/51003/html-preview)

Comment: I have downloaded and installed the HTML Preview Plugin you suggested and its functional and stable, but it's not as flexible and rich in features as in Visual studio, or Dreamweaver.

Comment: Netbeans is not strictly designed for web designing so there will be lack of support for design part. but if you are using chrome web browser their is a plugin for chrome as 'netbeans connector'. this can automatically update the html content in web browser when you make changes to the html page through netbeans. remember to run the html page using chrome (with netbeans connector).